# Max retries exceeded with url: /old/lk_api.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify

Tags: python, python-requests

**I try to autofill the form. What's the problem with that code**:

```
import requests

link = "https://e.mospolytech.ru/old/lk_api.php"
data = {"ulogin": "sssss", "upassword": "1223"}

response = requests.post(link, data=data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KIMz.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: If you are using `https` protocol in url means, server should have ssl cert installed in it.
You can turn off ssl verification. (which is not recommended).

`requests.post(link, data=data, verify=False)`

Comment: In short: broken server setup as can be seen from [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=e.mospolytech.ru): the certificate chain is incomplete. Apart from that please don't post text as image but copy + paste the error messages and stacktrace properly formatted into your question.